# How would I replace all pixels of a specific RGB in a PNG with another RGB in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'd use a canvas, but I'm not familiar with canvases and I want the image to look badly drawn. I want to replace all the white pixels in an image with a random colour, I've already figured out the random colour function but I don't know how to replace the pixels.

Comment: Do you mean replacing all white pixels with the same random colour, or each white pixel with an unique random colour?

Comment: the same colour.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use `getImageData()` and `putImageData()` to have pixel access to a canvas.

If you're wondering what's up with `i += 4`, the reason is that the image data returned by `getImageData()` is an array of Red/Green/Blue/Alpha values; we want to skip the alpha (opacity) value when comparing or changing things.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("c");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Draw something silly on the canvas for starters
function resetCanvas() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "purple";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.font = "bold 65px sans-serif";
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.fillText("eyyy", 15, 100);
}

function replaceColor(srcR, srcG, srcB, dstR, dstG, dstB) {
  const im = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for (var i = 0; i < im.data.length; i += 4) {
    if (
      im.data[i] === srcR &&
      im.data[i + 1] === srcG &&
      im.data[i + 2] === srcB
    ) {
      im.data[i] = dstR;
      im.data[i + 1] = dstG;
      im.data[i + 2] = dstB;
    }
  }
  ctx.putImageData(im, 0, 0);
}

resetCanvas();
```

```html
<button onclick="resetCanvas()">Reset</button>
<button onclick="replaceColor(255, 255, 255, 255, 160, 0)">Replace white with orange</button>
<button onclick="replaceColor(255, 255, 255, Math.random() * 255, Math.random() * 255, Math.random() * 255)">Replace white with random</button>
<br />
<canvas id="c" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<br />
```